# character classification of strings in python

Tags: python

```
def isLower(ch):
    return ch in string.lowercase

def isLower(ch):
    return 'a' <= ch <= 'z'

def isLower(ch):
    return string.find(string.lowercase, ch) != -1
```

Which version of isLower you think will be
fastest? What are the other reasons besides speed to prefer one or
the other?

Comment: Look into the `timeit` module.  You can run your own benchmarks.  Also, what are you trying to figure out?  It has a lower case character?  If any character is lower case?  If all characters are lower case?

Comment: With the timeit module you can *know* which one is faster. Also, It may depend on the particular case, you could specify that, and which is good for what, it also heavily depends on the context which I recommend you to add in order to get better quality answers.

Comment: Also, `string.find()` is deprecated.

Answer (score 12):

`str` (and `unicode`) already has a `islower` method, which also works for multi-character strings. The `unicode` version also handles unicode characters correctly, unlike your attempts which assume ASCII (a capital sin for quite a few applications, and for all others, there is zero reason to impose this restriction as a more general version takes *even less* code, as it's built-in).

Also note that the `string` module is largely obsolete, many of its functions have been replaced by `str` methods - for instance, `string.find` is replaced by the `str.find` method. And `s1.find(s2) != -1` should be equivalent to `s2 in s1` if I remember correctly.